# Javascript - Calling asynchronous functions inside only one case(of switch-case) within an event handler

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, event-handling, es6-promise

```js
$(<someSelector>).on(<someEvent>, function() {
    switch(condition) {
       case <case1>:
           someAsyncFunction();
           break;
       case <case2>:
           syncFunction();
           break;
       ...
       <more cases>
    }
}
```

The part where I'm focusing on now is the case1.

My question here is, can I define the callback as an `async` so I can use `await` in the case1?
If not, if using plain `.then`/`.catch` do I need to call the `break` inside the `then`/`catch`/`finally` blocks or do I still keep it out of those like any other code?

I couldn't find any SO article with such a query. So would be glad if I'm pointed to one too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `can I define the callback as an async so I can use await in the case1?` Yes, absolutely, try it :)

Comment: "*If using plain .then/.catch do I need to call the break inside the then/catch/finally blocks*" - no, that won't work - you can try it! "*…or do I still keep it out of those like any other code?*" - yes.

Comment: I would turn the event handler into an async function and have the try catch within the case block.